# SSIS not giving expected result

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS, I have a derived column giving me a result I do not expect. For this formula in particular it's a simple ((200 * 29.7) - 5940) * 1 where I expect the value to be 0. However when looking at the result of this derived column I find the value to be 0.000000000000909494701772928!

The values used for this calculation were directly pulled from a database, and all of them are of the double precision float data type.

Unfortunately, simply changing the data type of my result column to integer would not help as I need those decimal places.

I am curious, what maybe the cause of such a number?

Comment: @MitchWheat the datatypes used for the input are all double precision float (DT_R8) which outputs to a column of the same type. Funnily enough I'm comparing my results to another BI tool (Cognos) and I'm getting very small values where it's supposed to evaluate to 0 (e.g. [479.4 - 479.4] * 1 = 5.68E-14) as well.

Comment: I suggest you use DECIMAL or NUMERIC instead of FLOAT if you want a reasonable number

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the discrepancy is numerical precision.

Try running these simple `SELECT`s in SSMS:

```
select (((cast(200 as numeric(9)) * cast(29.7 as numeric(9)) - cast(5940 as numeric(9))))) 
select (((cast(200 as numeric(38,17)) * cast(29.7 as numeric(38,17)) - cast(5940 as numeric(38,17)))))
```

As @Nick pointed out, use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` instead of `FLOAT`.

[decimal and numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)

The default precision of `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` is 18.

Change datatype from double-precision float `[DT_R8]` to `[DT_DECIMAL]`

Comment: Trying out your example above, I did a select statement where I cast each value to numeric(38,27) and got the expected result of 0.000000 (but I'm unsure why it's only showing 6dp) however running the same calculation in SSIS using the same precision and scale I got 0.000000000000909494701772928.

Comment: To update my earlier comment; after creating a new column to compute (((dt_numeric,38,27)200 * (dt_numeric,38,27)29.7) - (dt_numeric,38,27)5940) * (dt_numeric,38,27)1, it does give me 0.000000000000000000000000000. I may have to update my question to explain the situation better as this problem may be caused from the values I'm pulling from the database rather than the data type.